# Embedding Mp3 Deselects browser window?

Tags: firefox, mp3, embed

I'm working on a website and have an mp3 embedded in a page like this:

```
<embed src="/resources/mymusic.mp3" height="20" width="300" autostart="false" loop="true">
```

however when that page loads in Firefox the browser window gets deselected, hence disabling user interaction with various elements until they click inside the window again.  firefox is still the 
app in focus but the browser window itself becomes deselected.  this doesn't happen in Safari.

using:

```
 <object height="20" width="300" data="/resources/mymusic.mp3"></object>
```

gave the same result.

also tried

```
<audio controls>
   <source src="/resources/mymusic.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
```

element but it won't load at all in firefox.

Any suggestions on how to keep the window active?

Comment: in case anyone is interested i found a workaround for this problem by embedding google's audio player instead like this:
    `<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" quality="best" flashvars="audioUrl=/resources/mymusic.mp3width="300" height="27"></embed>`

Comment: as google discontinued the above services, the stand alone audio player can be grabbed from this site @ http://kingjazzy.com/audio-player.swf if anyone needs it.